# What is better approach "mysql on VM GCE" vs Google SQL Cloud

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I want to use a small mysql database in order to store some data that i going to calculate on a VM of GCE (by using Talend).

After store the data on the mysql i want to connect to it by using Excel, and update some registries.

What should be the best approach, install mysql on the VM or use Google Cloud SQL?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only you can decide what better fits your needs, but you may consider the following:

Local Mysql Pros:

- Faster performances. This could be important if generating a lot of queries you would need a bigger Cloud SQL instance to have similar speed.
- Minor costs

Cloud SQL Pros:

- High reliability. Data is backed-up without the need of taking snapshots.
- Possibility to stop or delete GCE instance and keep database active.
- Easier and faster to scale if required
- Easily add a read replica.
- Less load on the GCE

Sincerely,
Paolo

Comment: Thanks Paolo, i will try to use Local MySQL

Comment: @David I need to make the same decision. What was your findings? are you happy with using Local Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

For better performance you can run your MySQL server on a virtual machine. I have tried that with the same server specifications (1 CPU, 3.75 GB memory) and it runs much better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please watch your grammatic and spelling.

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck please don't suggest unnecessary edits and be a bit more kind to new contributors

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck your edit included boldings of "mysql" and "VM" and monospacing on the VM configuration, that's not needed. After all, you should not criticize wrong spelling and not correct the capitalization of MySQL

Comment: Thank you @Nico I decided to delete my comments, you were right. Because they were not related to the question.